# Automatically map the same props to multiple React components

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple React components that will receive the same props...

```
...
render () {
  const { someProps } = this.props

  return (
    <div className="someDiv">
      <Component1 someProps={someProps}/>
      <Component2 someProps={someProps}/>
    </div>
  )
}
...
```

The above code works fine but is there a more dynamic way of doing this? Mabye do a `.map()` over an array of Component names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array of components should work just fine.

```js
const Component1 = (props) => <div>Component 1</div>
const Component2 = (props) => <div>Component 2</div>
const Component3 = (props) => <div>Component 3</div>

const components = [Component1, Component2, Component3]

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { someProps } = this.props
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Root component</h3>
        {components.map((Component, index) =>
          <Component key={index} someProps={someProps} />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```